# opening all links on a page with a delay

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open all links on a page when the href contains certain text, at the moment I'm using

```
$('a[href*="/steve"]').each(function() {
  window.open($(this).attr('href') );   
});
```

now the page I'm using contains a lot of links with that text in the href so it spams me with open windows in a very short amount of time and I would like to add a delay so it has time to open and wait about 5 seconds before opening the next. I was trying to use .delay but can't get it working as I'm pretty new and didn't know exactly where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('a[href*="/steve"]').each(function(index) {
    setTimeout(
         function(href){window.open(href)},
         (index+1)*5000, $(this).attr('href')
    );
});
```

The idea is to call `setTimeout` with an ever increasing delay.

Comment: no need to use a variable. there is an `index` parameter passed to the `each` callback method. use that multiplied by the delay..

Comment: (*also IE does not support passing parameter to you functions through `setTimeout`*)

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout to add delay:

```
var i = 0;
$('a[href*="/steve"]').each(function() {
    ++i;
    setTimeout(function(href) { window.open(href) },i*5000, $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function as a parameter and `window.open` does not return one..

Comment: also `setTimeout` is run in the global scope. So `this` will point to the `window` object and not the `a` link..